# Transformers Masterforce/Victory - Does God Ginrai lose Jin chokon?

Tags: transformers

At the end of Transformers Masterforce God Ginrai and the other GodMasters fly off into space, leaving their human "components" (for want of a better word) behind.
My question is that since the humans are no longer a part of them, does this mean that they lose Jin chokon and are thus weaker? i.e. they only have Ten chokon and Chi chokon now?

Perhaps somebody has seen the some reference in the Victory toyline (box bio) or manga that mentions this? (I don't know if any were re-released for Victory / Zone).

It would explain why God Ginrai doesn't seem to be as kick-ass strong in Victory (I'm thinking of the battle with Deszarus).

Answer (score 1):

TFWiki states that the manga is a separate continuity, so no help there. However, it does [state](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/God_Ginrai#Super-God_Masterforce_cartoon):

> "With Devil Z's death, the bond he had forged between transtector and
>   human ceased to exist, and Ginrai and the other humans were separated
>   from their transtectors. The transtectors, however, had been evolved
>   through their partnership with the humans and continued to exist as
>   true super-robot life forms. Having been imprinted with his human
>   partner's personality, Ginrai's transtector departed for space to
>   pursue the surviving Decepticons and rejoin the greater war."

So one would assume that since they have evolved out of the need of a human partner they are no longer weak without them.

Comment: That is true, however I'm specifically asking whether or not they have Jin chokon power. Ten chokon and Chi chokon I believe they do, because the transtectors absorbed it over time. But they did not have a long time to absorb Jin chokon from the humans.

Comment: @VictorySaber - I'm far from being an expert on this particular part of the TF mythos, but it seems that the wiki article does hint that the transectors evolved having both chokons without their human partners.